# Calculating 'n' maximum value in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, max

I have a scenario. Output from previous [job1](http://pastebin.com/ADa8fTGB)

In next job I need to find `i` key having maximum value.*eg i=3, 3 keys having maximum value.*
(`i` will be a custom parameter)

How to approach this.

Should we calculated `max` in job2 mapper as there will be unique keys, as the output is coming from previous reducer 
or 
find `max` in second jobs reducer.But again how to find `i` keys?

**Update**

I tried in this way 
Instead of emiting value as value in reducer.I emitted value as key so I can get the values in ascending order.
And I wrote the next MR job.where mapper simply emits the key/value.

Reducer finds the max of key 
But again I am stuck that cannot be done as we try to get the id , because id is only unique,Values are not uniqe.

How to solve this.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find top `i` keys with `PriorityQueue`. Simple code to illustrate the idea:

```
public static class TopNMapper extends Mapper<IntWritable, DoubleWritable, IntWritable, DoubleWritable> {
    private static class MyPair implements Comparable<MyPair> {
        public final int key;
        public final double value;

        MyPair(int key, double value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(MyPair o) {
            return -Double.compare(value, o.value); // i'm not sure about '-'
        }
    }

    private final PriorityQueue<MyPair> topN = new PriorityQueue<MyPair>();

    @Override
    protected void map(IntWritable key, DoubleWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (Double.isNaN(value.get())) {
            return; // not a number
        }
        topN.add(new MyPair(key.get(), value.get()));
        if (topN.size() <= 50) { // simple optimization
            return;
        }
        while (topN.size() > 3) { // retain only top 3 elements in queue
            topN.poll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        while (topN.size() > 3) {
            topN.poll(); // retain only top 3 elements in queue
        }
        for (MyPair myPair : topN) { // write top 3 elements
            context.write(new IntWritable(myPair.key), new DoubleWritable(myPair.value));
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this mapper (one for all input), you should get 3 keys with maximum values​​.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply: But not displaying the correct value .See my edit

Comment: 1. `if (topN.size() <= 50) {` this line need not to update `topN` on every new key value, you can remove it.
2. Why the second output is wrong?

Comment: ok. One more doubt Alexey.What if my mapper contains only 2 values.Will it return 2 itself?

Comment: I see no problem in this case, mapper should return 2 elements.